# How to get related type post id in magic field plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am using magic field plugin for my project and created two related type fields and I want to get selected post/page id. Please help me I am stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the loop you can say:

```
<?php echo get('field_name') ?>
```

Replace field_name with the name of your field. This should print it's contents.

Comment: Link-only answers are deprecated, since they undergo "link rot". Could you post the relevant example in your answer?